# How to pass assignment operators as parameters to web url?

Tags: url

I need to call an API and search for instances of ImageAge>40 days
I can pass string parameters in url but I dont know how to filter with assignment operator. 
Url I am trying to access is like this
https://randomurl.com/v1/instances?{parametername}>{parametervalue}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Google "URL encoding"

Comment: Tried, not working